# pos_hint, DragBehavior and FloatLayout - possible conflict - how to resolve it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have a FloatLayout with 04 buttons, positioned with pos_hint (left, right, top, bottom). **Where pos_hint is ZERO, the Btn has a DoF**, otherwise it cannot be moved.
I tryied to positioning my buttons with pos, but it was not possible. **How to** set the initial position and leave the btns draggable? **Thank you** for your help! **:)**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
<DragBtn>:
    # Define the properties for the DragLabel
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 10000000
    drag_distance: 0
    
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 150,150        
    on_touch_down: print(self.pos)

FloatLayout:
                  ##########################
                  # Btn2                   #
                  #                   Btn4 #
                  # Btn1     Btn3          #
                  ##########################    
    DragBtn:
        text: 'Btn1'
        pos_hint: {'left':0, 'bottom':0} # free
    DragBtn:
        text: 'Btn2'
        pos_hint: {'left':0, 'top':1} # just move on x
    DragBtn:
        text: 'Btn3'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'bottom':0} # just move on y
    DragBtn:
        text: 'Btn4'
        pos_hint: {'right':1, 'top':.5} # locked
'''

class DragBtn(DragBehavior, Button): pass
class TestApp(App): 
    def build(self): return Builder.load_string(kv)
TestApp().run()
```

Comment: It is not the zero values that are allowing movement, it is the fact that `left` and `bottom` are not legal values for `pos_hint` and are therefore ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can just calculate the starting positions:

```
DragBtn:
    text: 'Btn1'
    pos: 0,0
    # pos_hint: {'left':0, 'bottom':0} # free
DragBtn:
    text: 'Btn2'
    pos: 0, root.height - self.height
    # pos_hint: {'left':0, 'top':1} # just move on x
DragBtn:
    text: 'Btn3'
    pos: root.center_x - self.width/2, 0
    # pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'bottom':0} # just move on y
DragBtn:
    text: 'Btn4'
    pos: root.width - self.width, root.center_y - self.height/2
    # pos_hint: {'right':1, 'top':.5} # locked
```

Comment: Hi John, Thank you again.